# How do I use LSTM Networks for time-series classification problems?

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, matlab

I have 2 binary outputs (1 and 0) with time series data. The dataset order is shown in the image.[image].Can anyone suggest me how to handle this problem with LSTM? Particularly in MATLAB or Python. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with RNN/LSTM/GRU (type of Neural Networks that are well-suited for time-series).

For example : https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

This example is quite similar to the problem mentioned in question (predict air quality based on ~10 parameters. Parameters are available as a time-series).

Comment: @shamit..Thank you for a useful answer.....What if i remove the time and date coloumn and implement in LSTM?.Is it a good idea to remove time series and apply remaining inputs to LSTM?

Comment: Yes, do try that version (data minus time / date columns). Also try creation of derived columns (Like time of day, month) to capture seasonality in data (Like temperature in  month of May  @ 11 AM vs 11 AM in Dec.